# UIGestureRecognizer not receiving touches during UIScrollView deceleration

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I've been trying to create a `UITextView` subclass that handles swiping away the keyboard like in the Message.app.

I have a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` added to the `keyWindow` of my app, and the gesture delegate is configured for `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer`. Everything works fine except for when the `UIScrollView` is decelerating, during that phase it is possible to pan without the touches being registered.

You can take a look at a very simple [github sample project here](https://github.com/mikeahmarani/MADismissiveTextView).

I have tried adding the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` directly to the viewController.view and to the scrollView, same issue occurs. I have also tried setting `scrollView.panGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:` with my `UITextView` subclass gesture recognizer.

Any ideas as to why this may be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a new `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, maybe you could use the one on the `UIScrollView`, and add your own pan logic to that gesture recognizer with `- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action`.

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think of this first. The UIScrollView panGesture was clearly working, may as well use it. Simplifies the code too. Thanks!